# Vba search and paste solution

Tags: vba, search, vlookup, paste

i would like to come up with vba sub that searching value from one specified cell (job) across all sheets and then pastes rows but only with selected columns. If value not found any error message instead paste value.

I know it's bigger project but I'm fresh so try to my best.

As far i have solution for whole rows:

```
Sub TEST()

Dim tws As String
Dim l_row As String
Dim l_rowR As String
Dim job As String
Dim i As Integer
 
Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

tws.Range("A20") = "STATS:"
 
job = tws.Range("B5")
 
lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
lastRowRpt = tws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
For i = 3 To lastRow
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value = job And _
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = "x2" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
    lastRowRpt = tws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    tws.Range("A" & lastRowRpt + 1).Select
    tws.Paste
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use `Intersect` to specify particular columns.

Comment: Can you please provde un example how can I use this? Thanks